# Why my code get the largest int 2147483647 not zero?

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql

It should be `0`, but I get it in java it comes out：`2147483647`.

I test in navicat:

[image]

The produce code is this:

```
BEGIN
declare itype int(1) default 0;    
declare zdAreaCode varchar(20) ;
declare icount int(8) default 0;
declare iicount int(8) default 0;
declare i int ;
/*declare iserror int(1) default 0;
declare continue HANDLER for SQLEXCEPTION set iserror=1;*/
set out_a=60;
set out_b=35;
set out_c=72;
set out_d=3;
set out_e='';
set out_f='';
set out_g='';
set out_h='';
set out_i='0100001000';
set out_j='10';
set out_k=90;
set out_l='';
set out_m=0;
set out_n=0;
set out_o='';
insert into D09 select in_a,in_b,in_c,in_d,in_e,in_f,in_g,in_h,in_i,in_j,in_k,in_l,in_m,in_o,0,in_n,date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s');

select count(*) into icount from  X02 where X0201=1 and X0202=in_a;
if icount=0 then
   insert into X02 select 1,in_a,'',date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s') ;
else
   update X02 set X0204=date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s') where X0201=1 and X0202=in_a;
end if;

select count(*) into icount from X04 where X0401=in_a and X0407=0;/*系统参数*/
if icount>0 THEN
 select X0403,X0405 into zdAreaCode,itype from X04 where X0401=in_a and X0407=0;
 set i=0;

  while (i<3) and (iicount=0) DO
    select count(*) into iicount from M02 where substr(M0201,1,6-i*2)=substr(zdAreaCode,1,6-i*2);
    if iicount=0 THEN
      set i=i+1;
    end if;
  end while;
  if iicount>0 THEN
   select M0204,M0205,M0206,M0208,M0209,M0211,M0212 into out_a,out_b,out_c,out_d,out_i,out_j,out_k from M02
    where substr(M0201,1,6-i*2)=substr(zdAreaCode,1,6-i*2);
  end if;
  if itype=0 THEN 
    set i=0;
    set iicount=0;
    while (i<3) and (iicount=0) DO
    select count(*) into iicount from E01 where substr(E0101,1,6-i*2)=substr(zdAreaCode,1,6-i*2);
    if iicount=0 THEN
      set i=i+1;
    end if;
   end while;
   if iicount>0 THEN
    select E0102,E0103,E0104,E0105 into out_e,out_f,out_g,out_h from E01 where substr(E0101,1,6-i*2)=substr(zdAreaCode,1,6-i*2);
   end if;
  end if;
  select count(*) into iicount from R06 where R0601=in_a;
  if iicount>0 THEN
    select R0603,R0604,R0602 into out_l,out_m,out_n from R06 where R0601=in_a;
  end if;
  select count(*) into icount from R05 where R0501=1 and R0504=in_a; 
  if icount>0 then
    select distinct R0508 into out_o from R05 where R0501=1 and R0504=in_a;
  ELSE
   set out_o='';
  end if;
  
end if;
END
```

Test Code is below:

```
call P_A_ParamInit("", "P1111", "ad", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "10", "1.0", "1.0", "0", "06DD501FF80811E69414FA163E59CFD5", "20170301111111", "511321199001031598", @a, @b, @c, @d, @e, @f, @g, @h, @i, @j, @k, @l, @m, @n, @o);
SELECT @a, @b, @c, @d, @e, @f, @g, @h, @i, @j, @k, @l, @m, @n, @o;
```

It should be `0`.

But in my code:

```
resultmap.put("c14", outParam_paraInit.get(28));  // get the `m`
```

[image]

You see, it turns into `2147483647` , the largest int number.
Why it is not `0`?

Comment: Please post the code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

integers are made up from a 4 bytes, if all the bits in those bytes are set to 1's then that number is the binary equivelent of 2147483647.

EDIT:

Since adding you're code I am none the wiser, it appears to be that you are getting some unexpected result from the code but he code is just a load of cryptic variable names that don't really explain your objective.

The nature of the code and question as written makes it hard to determine if the logic is at fault so I would be inclined to say step through it with a debugger and see what values you have at each step.

Comment: ， How can I get the int (0)? or how can I convert back to 0?

Comment: No idea, your question actually makes no sense, my answer was simply explaining the value you're seeing. You need to post the code that produces this output.

Comment: You haven't explained what this code is doing at all, it's a complete mess! 
You say that the number next to 28 should be 0 but I have no idea from this how you produce those numbers or what they are supposed to mean so sorry but I don't think I can help you further.